# What can LVM do that standard partition can't?

Tags: hard-drive, lvm

I haven't spent much time dealing with standard partition. Aside from "LVM makes it easier" to manage disk, what really can LVM do that standard partition can't?

All I can think of right now is that your LV(Logical Volume) can be a combination of multiple hard disks. Can you also add size to your volume by shrinking another volume in standard partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A big one is snapshots -  freezing a copy of the disk at a point in time. This is useful for full partition backups.

Another is that logical space is abstracted from physical space, so if you delete a logical volume (partition) you can allocate its space to any other volume, even if space is not sequential.  IE *"you also add size to your volume by shrinking another volume in standard partition?"* - **YES**

You can retrofit RAID.